# How to insert a modified ELF loader given the current ELF loader is present?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

I need to modify the ELF loader's kernel implementation of an Ubuntu 14.04 distribution. Having downloaded the sources using:

```
sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

I ran the configuration script:

```
make config
```

in the root source tree. After a seemingly endless sequence of input requests, the script created the `.config` file needed to build the kernel (or a set of modules). The kernel version that I am using is `linux-3.13.0`, and it has the following source tree layout:

```
$ ls 
arch              Documentation      fs          kernel          README             sound
block             drivers            include     lib             REPORTING-BUGS     tools
COPYING           dropped.txt        init        MAINTAINERS     samples            ubuntu
CREDITS           elf.dat            ipc         Makefile        scripts            usr
crypto            FileSystemMake     Kbuild      mm              security           virt
debian.master     firmware           Kconfig     net             shortcuts
```

The ELF loader is located in `/path/to/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c`. Following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module), in order to compile an individual module it is sufficient to run

```
make /path/to/module/directory
```

In this case that would be:

```
make /path/to/source/fs
```

The compilation is quite lengthy; it takes about twenty minutes (on a virtual machine) and the output is written (by default) in the same directory in which the module is located. I've found the object files by running:

```
find . -name "*.o"
```

in `/path/to/source/fs`. Filtering by name, the ELF loader can be located by running:

```
find . -name "*elf*.o"
```

In the current sources it is written (by default) in:

```
/path/to/source/fs/binfmt_elf.o
```

Having gone through [this tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html), I've noticed that kernel modules have the naming convention `module_name.ko` in order to distinguish them from user space object files.

How can I insert the new (modified) ELF loader into the kernel, given that the current ELF loader is present (and unloading it may prevent binaries from being executed)?

Comment: I'm just curious why you needed to use `find` to find `binfmt_elf.o` in `/path/to/source/fs` when you already knew that `binfmt_elf.c` was in that directory.

Comment: Yes, the source file was indeed but I haven't found any documentation on the output layout(where exactly are the kernel modules written) so I had to find() it.

Comment: You need a `make modules` step to adapt the `.o` files to be suitable for loading as modules, givin you the `.ko` files.